# Error "NameError: name 'logdir' is not defined"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

As beginner, I am following the tutorials from the tensorflow website. 
In the regression part, I am getting the following error

**command:** size_histories['Tiny'] = compile_and_fit(tiny_model, 'sizes/Tiny')

**Error:**

NameError: name 'logdir' is not defined

I will really appreciate any help.

The complete error message is here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-6b42ade0df41> in <module>
----> 1 size_histories['Small'] = compile_and_fit(small_model, 'sizes/Small')

<ipython-input-20-37c172377a6c> in compile_and_fit(model, name, optimizer, max_epochs)
     16     epochs=max_epochs,
     17     validation_data=validate_ds,
---> 18     callbacks=get_callbacks(name),
     19     verbose=0)
     20   return history

<ipython-input-19-1fd695b661fd> in get_callbacks(name)
      3     tfdocs.modeling.EpochDots(),
      4     tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_binary_crossentropy', patience=200),
----> 5     tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir/name),
      6   ]

NameError: name 'logdir' is not defined
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell, but I would guess that `compile_and_fit` contains code that you wrote?   And in that code, somewhere, the name `logdir` is being used without first having a value assigned to it. Unless you paste the full backtrace of the error message, we can only speculate blindly as to where the problem might be.  (But if you yourself take the time to look at each line of the backtrace, you will probably see that it explicitly tells you on what line of what file the problem is occurring.)

Comment: Thanks, I have added the complete error message.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by googling `"compile_and_fit" "tiny_model" logdir` I found that the tutorial you're following must be https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit

As the backtrace tells you, `compile_and_fit()` calls `get_callbacks()`, which in turn uses the variable `logdir`.   `logdir` is not passed directly to `get_callbacks()` as a parameter, nor is it defined anywhere inside the function. 
 So, `get_callbacks()` gets to that line, sees the name `logdir`, fails to find anything of that name in its local variables, and therefore tries to access a *global* variable of that name instead.   But Python is complaining that *nothing* of that name exists at all, not even a global variable—so I guess you must have skipped the earlier part of the tutorial, where you would have set up that global variable:

```
logdir = pathlib.Path(tempfile.mkdtemp())/"tensorboard_logs"
shutil.rmtree(logdir, ignore_errors=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes I had naively skipped the lines. Have a great day!!